# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment in if statement

Tags: javascript

I get this error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
>   script.js:37 visaType script.js:37 (anonymous function)

This is the code:

**script.js:**

```
  function visaType() {
    var visaOld = $('#inputVisaOld').val();
    var visaNew = $('#inputVisaNew').val();

    if (visaOld = 'Studying Mandarin Chinese' && visaNew = 'Foreign Student') {
      // the error message points here
      return '<div class="alert alert-info" Documents for FR -> FS</div>'; 
    } else if (visaOld = 'Tourism' && visaNew = 'Joining Taiwananese Family') {
      return '<div class="alert alert-info" Documents for P -> TS</div>'; 
    } else {
      return '<div class="alert alert-error>Not allowed to change</div>'; 
    }
  }
```

**html:**

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputVisa">Current Visa <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputVisaOld" placeholder="Enter Current Visa">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputVisa">New Visa</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputVisaNew" placeholder="Enter Visa to Apply">
    </div>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`visaOld = 'Studying Mandarin Chinese'` has single `=` sign which means you're assigning when you should be comparing: `visaOld === 'Studying Mandarin Chinese'`

It's in a few spots, not just that one.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison operator in Javascript is `==`, not `=`. So it should be:

```
if (visaOld == 'Studying Mandarin Chinese' && visaNew == 'Foreign Student') {
  // the error message points here
  return '<div class="alert alert-info" Documents for FR -> FS</div>'; 
} else if (visaOld == 'Tourism' && visaNew == 'Joining Taiwananese Family') {
  return '<div class="alert alert-info" Documents for P -> TS</div>'; 
} else {
  return '<div class="alert alert-error>Not allowed to change</div>'; 
}
```

`=` is for variable assignment.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal There's no need to use `===` for these comparisons.

Comment: How about two reasons: maintainability and clarity of intent? Obviously, you don't *have* to use `===` here, but it's generally agreed that it's better to do so.

Comment: That's your style, don't impose it on others. If you feel like commenting, do so, but don't edit someone else's answer like that.

Comment: In general, you should not make semantic changes when editing answers. Anything more than fixing formatting or obvious typos should be done as comments.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal Remember that not everybody agrees with these blanket (Crockford) rules like: always use strict equality, never use `new`, never use pre increment. You should only edit the code if it's really wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One of the oldest mistakes in programming. Your assignments should be comparisons.  Use `==` instead of `=` and it'll work.

Why current code had a syntax error:

Assignment (`=`) comes after `&&` in operator precedence. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence So your statement is being evaluated like the following

```
if (visaOld = ('Studying Mandarin Chinese' && visaNew) = 'Foreign Student') {
```

Use parentheses to force what you want

```
if ((visaOld = 'Studying Mandarin Chinese') && (visaNew = 'Foreign Student')) {
```

But remember, assignment within an if statement is not recommended and also not what you intended.